# mupdf cannot recognize version marker

Tags: android, mupdf

When opening and decrypting a file into a buffer in Android, and trying to open the file using Mupdf OpenBuffer method, it fails with the following message:

**cannot recognize version marker**

The viewer shows all the pages blank, although it gets number of pages in document correctly.

The same buffer when saved to a file and opening that file, it works perfectly.

I have compared the code I use to the Mupdf sample, and didn't find anything significant difference.

What might be the cause of this ? Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error means:

> the first 5 bytes of the file were not %PDF-

You could try adding:

```
printf("first bytes are: %d, %d, %d, %d, %d", buf[0], buf[1], buf[2], buf[3], buf[4]);
```

to the file `pdf-xref.c` in function `pdf_load_version()` - the line before the `memcmp`. This might reveal what's actually in the buffer, perhaps it has somehow gone through a string conversion of something?

Comment: Yes indeed, there were some garbage before the PDF header, but what is even weirder is that when the same buffer is saved to a file it is opened by what ever viewer without problems. Thanks!